# Custom field on home.php

Tags: wordpress

I'm using a custom field to change the colour of the header on all pages. Problem is, the home.php doesn't qualify as a Page.

Even if I change

```
 <?php
 /**
  * The Template for displaying all single posts.
  *
  */
 ?>
```

To

```
 <?php
 /**
  * Template Name: Groups
  */
  ?>
```

If I choose this template in the admin, with the Groups page, and fill in the custom field it appears to just use the index.php, which I don't want.

At the moment it seems nigh impossible to achieve this? any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure to understand, but could you just put a standard header color on home page and overwrite it in other pages (you said it work ?)

If not, you can test if the page is home page with

```
if(is_front_page()) :
//add custom class to header
endif;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking specifically to test for home.php, this function will work as well:

```
    if(is_home();) {
    //custom styles
    }
```